# Avoid overwritting constructor content

Tags: java, methods, input, constructor, getter-setter

so I have a program that ask(input) for stuff(variable int string etc..)and those elements are after that passed to the constructor.However, each time I input new values,previous are overwritten.How do I make it create a new one instead of overwritting the previous values?I am very new to Java and im kinda confuse.Heres my code:

```
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);   //user input the name
    System.out.print("name: \n");
    String name = scan1.nextLine();
```

and then pass it to the constructor:

```
Balloon aballoon = new Balloon(name);
```

my constructor looks like

```
  public Balloon(String name){


        setName(name);
```

and the method of it

```
public String thename
public void setName(String name){
if(name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+$")){  
thename = name;
}
```

So yeah im wondering how to build multiple object(character) whitout overwritting the previous one,and how to store them(the character).

thank you

Comment: You could use an array

Comment: could you show me how? like I said im a beginner.But I will need to be able to retrieve/delete/edit character later--does an array just dump bunch of data in it? cause If it does I wont be able to retrieve a specific element?

Comment: First off, I'd recommend using a class name other than Character, as that is a java wrapper class(already used) and can cause confusion; indeed, I got very confused when I first read through this.

Also, when you are writing the program, do you know how many 'Characters' you need to make, or will it change depending on different things?

Comment: this isnt the real class name,I just changed it for privacy(post edited to make it easier to read).And I have to be able to input as much "balloon" I want,without limit.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining how to make and use an ArrayList, and how to iterate through that ArrayList to modify/delete data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList<Balloon>` to store multiple `Balloon` objects:

```
ArrayList<Balloon> baloons = new ArrayList<Balloon>;

//Read name

baloons.add(new Balloon(name));

//baloons now contains the baloon with the name name
```

For more information on how to use the `ArrayList` class, see [Class `ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: But as I replied to kirbyquerby, I need to be able to retrieve/modify/delete specific element--does an array allows that or its just a bunch of unordered data?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve, modify and delete objects in `ArrayList`s. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: another thing,why when i try to print the object created(aballoon),it prints something like "Balloon@4554617c"?how to make it prints the object value(s) instead of this(name)

Comment: What you are printing right now is just the `abaloon` object, but I do assume that you want to print the name of it. To print out the name of `abaloon`, call `System.out.println(abaloon.name)`.

Comment: Oops, you named the field `thename`. So use `System.out.println(abaloon.thename)` instead.

Comment: thanks.Im currently trying stuff with your explanation.Ill get you back on that

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop akin to something like the following to store all the balloons that the user wants:

```
List<Balloon> balloonList = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
String prompt="Name?(Enter 'done' to finish inputting names)";



System.out.println(prompt);                 //print the prompt
String userInput=input.nextLine();          //get user input

while(!userInput.equals("done")){           //as long as user input is not
                                            //"done", adds a new balloon
                                            //with name specified by user
    balloonList.add(new Balloon(userInput));
    System.out.println(prompt);             //prompt user for more input
    userInput=input.nextLine();             //get input
}
```

For modify, I'm going to assume that you wish to find the balloon using its name(IE: If someone wants to delete/modify the balloon with the name "bob", it will delete/modify the (first) balloon in the ArrayList that has the name "bob".

For deletion, it is simple- write a a simple method to find the balloon specified(if it is in the list) and delete it.

```
public static boolean removeFirst(List<Balloon> balloons, String balloonName){
    for(int index=0;index<balloons.size();index++){//go through every balloon
        if(balloons.get(index).theName.equals(balloonName){//if this is the ballon you are looking for
            balloons.remove(index);//remove it
            return true;//line z
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method  will look for the Balloon specified by name and remove the first instance of it, returning true if it actually found and removed the balloon, otherwise removing it. If you wish to remove all balloons by that name, you can create a boolean b at the beginning of the method and set it to false. Then, you can change line z to

```
b=true;
```

and then at the bottom of the method, return b.

Now, by edit, you could mean one of two things. If you're planning on modifying the actual name of the balloon, you can use a loop like the one I made above and just modify the name when you find it, again you can make it modify all balloons with that name, or just the first one you find.

Or, if by modify a balloon you mean to replace the balloon in the ArrayList with a new balloon that has a different name, you will want to use the following methods:

```
balloons.remove(i);//remove balloon at index
balloons.add(i,newBalloon);//put the new balloon(with different data) at the index of the old one
```

Comment: thanks for your explaining;however my case might cause a problem here; I ask for a baloon,but after I ask for a color and number.So the color and number need to be assigned to the right balloon;Could you edit your code by considering this? thanks

Comment: Store the name, color and number in temporary variables then create the balloon with the variables when you're done passing them all in. I will not write all your code for you, but I can tell you how to do it.